# WPF EventTriggers - Cannot convert string 'DragOver' in attribute 'RoutedEvent' to object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEvent' in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, eventtrigger

I have implemented some triggers for a WPF button as below:

```
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragOver">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource swap}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadein}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource reset}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadeout}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource reset}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadeout}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

This is working perfectly in Visual Studio 2015, but in Visual Studio 2008 it is thrown below error:

```
Cannot convert string 'DragOver' in attribute 'RoutedEvent' to object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEvent'
```

I have changed above routed events within event triggers to:

- RoutedEvent="DragOver"  -> RoutedEvent="Mouse.DragOver"
- RoutedEvent="DragLeave" -> RoutedEvent="Mouse.DragLeave"
- RoutedEvent="Drop"      -> RoutedEvent="Mouse.Drop"

Mouse.DragOver, Mouse.DragLeave, Mouse.Drop are not recognized by xaml parser, it is highlighted.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I need to preceed the routed events with Button and a period like below. Now is working:

```
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragOver">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource swap}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadein}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource reset}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadeout}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Drop">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource reset}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource fadeout}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```